# Guid.Parse() ou new Guid()?

Tags: c#, .net, guid

Qual a principal diferença entre usar as opções `Guid.Parse()` ou `new Guid()` para converter uma *string* em um `Guid`?

E qual das duas abordagens seria melhor de utilizar?

`var usuarioId = new Guid(User.Identity.GetUserId())`

Ou

`var usuarioId = Guid.Parse(User.Identity.GetUserId())`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essencialmente nenhuma, exceto pelo fato que um é um construtor e o outro é um método de fabricação.

[Fonte do construtor](http://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Guid.cs,4329442fa037af5c,references).

[Fonte do Factory Method](http://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Guid.cs,3f3098bce93ed8a6,references) (este é chamado do original logo acima do fonte dele, só verificando se a *string* é válida). Note que o código já usa otimizações do C# 7.x

Em ambos quem faz o *parse* é o interno [`TryParseGuid()`](http://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Guid.cs,0fb93055f76993d8).

[Documentação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.guid.newguid?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).